# Object Validation (Match Similar Objects)

Tags: c#, .net, validation

I am trying to compare a list of objects to and Object and pick the one that best fit the description or pick the one that is closest in similarity to the Object used as the validation. lets say I have something like:

```
 public class Person
{
    public string FNqme { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public string Job { get; set; }
    public string Car { get; set; }
}
```

the data looks like this:

```
       string[] person1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"../../../person1.txt");  
    string[] person2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"../../../person2.txt");
    string[] person3 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"../../../person3.txt");  
    string[] person4 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"../../../person4.txt");
```

and the person used for validation:

```
string[] validator=System.IO.File.ReadAllLines@"../../../personUsedForValidation.txt");
```

how do I select the object that is closest in similarities or best match with the validator object?

```
for instance Person1 FName = Foo, LName = Baa, Job = waiter, Car = Toyota
         Person2 FName = Nanny, LName = Benny, Job = cashier, Car = Nissan
         Person3 FName = Fiona, LName = Byron, Job = Nurse, Car = Ford
```

Validator FName = Nanny, LName = King, Job = cashier, Car = Tesler.

I want to be able to select person 2 out of all the objects as it seem to be the closest to the validator string.

please excuse my bad English.

Comment: pls note. the last block of code is me explaining what the data structure looks like. its not part of the code

Comment: Hi can you provide more info about this. Wyy do you use class and string[]

Comment: hello, sorry for the confusion. the class is to show the kind of object structure I have and the string is to give an idea how the kind of data I have in array. my main array looks like this... List<Person> _person = new List... you get the idea. I showed that in order to simplify the post.

Comment: You need to define in a precise way what you mean with "Similar" and how you decide that a person is "more Similar to Validator" than the other one. (why `validator`? sounds not the right name for this variable). That's something you need to do before trying to write any code

Comment: @Giano Paolo If you search for a red car in France it will give you a bunch of results of red cars in France but it will also give you red Cars in London. By similar I mean your search criteria is similar to the result eg. (Red car) shows  you pictures of red cars all over the world and adding the other query (France) narrow the search and make it more precise and similar to what you seek i.e red Cars in France. Query = red car in France. Result shows match of RED CARS IN FRANCE. Now there are other results but the most similar one to validator or in this case query is what i want.